# Is this function preimage resistant?

Tags: algorithm, prng, hash-function

One of the ways of testing strength of PRNG functions is to design tests that distinguish PRNG
outputs from random strings: we are given a box which outputs PRNG(u) for some u or a random string.
We have to determine if the output comes from PRNG.
Assume that a hash function H fails this test.

Does it mean that it is not second preimage resistant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume a 256-bit cryptographic hash function `h` with all the properties that are expected from such.

Construct the function which, for any input string `s`, returns the first 255 bits of `h(s)` followed by the bit `0`.

This function is easy to distinguish from random with good probability given enough inputs: it returns only even numbers. But it is still tricky to compute any sort of collision or preimage for it: it is 255-bit strong.

Resistance to collision or preimage is not an all-or-nothing question. There are gradations.